# Migrar MYSQL A LARAVEL10

Tags: laravel-10

Alguno me podria ayudar o explicar bien como puedo migrar mi tabla de sql a Laravel 10...
Para esto tengo mi tabla Empleados que toma como claves foraneas Sexo, Departamento, puesto, sucursal, pero en las tablas independientes las referencias que toma, son de tipo "Unique", ya que son claves unicas de sucursales y me marca un error a la hora de hacer el "php artisan migrate", me dice que las claves foraneas no se estan bien declaradas y no se si sea respecto  al tipo de dato o sea algun otro problema, si pudieran ayudarme se los agradeceria mucho, ya que me interesa seguir aprendiendo este Framework y no darme por vencido...
Esta es mi tabla Sexo:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sexo` (
`id_sexo` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`sexo` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id_sexo)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 
COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

Esta es mi tabla Puesto:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `puesto` (
`id_puesto` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Clave_puesto` int(11) unique NOT NULL,
`Desc_corta_p` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`Descripcion_p` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id_puesto)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 
COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

Esta es mi tabla departamento:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `departamento` (
`id_departamento` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Clave_departamento` int(11) NOT NULL unique,
`Desc_corta_d` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`Descripcion_d` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id_departamento)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 
COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

Esta es mi tabla sucursal:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sucursal` (
`id_sucursal` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Clave_sucursal` int(11)  NOT NULL UNIQUE,
`Nom_sucrusal` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id_sucursal)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 
COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

Tabla Empleado:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Empleado`(
`id_empleado` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Clave_empleado` int(255) NOT NULL unique,
`nombre` varchar (55) NOT NULL,
`apellidoP`varchar (55) NOT NULL,
`apellidoM` varchar (55) NOT NULL,
`sexo_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`curp` varchar (55) NOT NULL,
`rfc` varchar (55) NOT NULL,
`nss` int (11) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar (55) NOT NULL,
`tel_casa` int (55) NOT NULL,
`celular` varchar (55) NOT NULL,
`foto_emple` varchar (255) NOT NULL,
`puesto_id` int NOT NULL,
`departamento_id` int NOT NULL,
`sucursal_id` int NOT NULL,
`estatus` varchar (55) NOT NULL,
`fecha_contrat` datetime  NULL,
`fecha_alta` datetime  NULL,
`fecha_baja` datetime  NULL,



PRIMARY KEY (id_empleado), 
FOREIGN KEY (sexo_id) REFERENCES sexo(id_sexo),
FOREIGN KEY (puesto_id) REFERENCES puesto (Clave_puesto),
FOREIGN KEY (departamento_id) REFERENCES 
departamento(Clave_departamento),
FOREIGN KEY (sucursal_id) REFERENCES 
sucursal(Clave_sucursal)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 
COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

Agradeceria Mucho su apoyo, Soy autodidacta